# Proof that if $X$ is a connected graph and $T\subseteq X$ is a maximal tree, then $q:X\to X/T$ is a homotopy equivalence

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology

I am trying to proof that if $X$ is a connected graph and $T\subseteq X$ is a maximal tree, then the quotient map $q:X\to X/T$ is a homotopy equivalence. 
I know it can be proven with the homotopy extention propriety (as shown by Hatcher in "Algebraic Topology", Proposition 0.17), but I was looking for a more direct proof. 
I tried to find another function $p$ so that $p\circ q$ and $q\circ p$ are homotopic to the indentity function but I couldn't. 
Thanks.

Comment: This is because the pair $(X,T)$ is a good pair and trees are contractible. I had to prove this in my Algebraic Topology course :)

Comment: @aldodecristo I know but you're referring to the proof with the homotopy extension propriety.

Comment: It's good to start with simpler cases. Can you find a suitable $p$ when $T$ is a single edge?